# ansible-playbook --limit more than one host?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

For various reasons/limitations I cannot make new groups in the inventory file and need to use `--limit/-l` to specify the hosts.

I was told to do something like:

`ansible-playbook -i /path/to/my/inventory/file.ini -l server.1.com server.2.com my-playbook.yml --check --diff`

This was throwing an error:

`ERROR! the playbook: server.2.com could not be found`

From the [Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#patterns-and-ansible-playbook-flags) on this subject I found that you could use a separate file to list all the hosts you want to limit.
Something like:

`ansible-playbook -i /path/to/my/inventory/file.ini -l @list-to-limit.txt my-playbook.yml`

However, I need to do it all inline without creating an additional file.

Comment: You can also use wildcards.

Answer (score 17):

The same [Common patters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#common-patterns) apply to the command-line option `-l`. Quoting the note:

> *"You can use either a comma (,) or a colon (:) to separate a list of hosts. The comma is preferred when dealing with ranges and IPv6 addresses."*

For example, given the inventory

```sh
shell> cat hosts
[webservers]
test_01
test_02

[dbservers]
test_03
test_04
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

The various host's patterns work as expected. For example

1. All hosts in webservers plus all hosts in dbservers

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml -l webservers:dbservers
...
ok: [test_01] => 
  inventory_hostname: test_01
ok: [test_02] => 
  inventory_hostname: test_02
ok: [test_03] => 
  inventory_hostname: test_03
ok: [test_04] => 
  inventory_hostname: test_04
```

2. The hosts test_02 and test_04

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml  -l test_02,test_04

ok: [test_02] => 
  inventory_hostname: test_02
ok: [test_04] => 
  inventory_hostname: test_04
```

3. All hosts in webservers except the host test_02

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml  -l webservers:\!test_02

  inventory_hostname: test_01
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is how to do it:

```
ansible-playbook ./your_playbook --limit "host1,host2,host3,host4"
```

Comment: This has already been posted.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider no It doesn't posted, I can see only -l but -l doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

I was spacing out and at the time I totally thought I could just list out all the hosts inline and `ansible-playbook` would understand.

I fixed my issue by simply adding `-l` before each host name in the command.

(I realize this might not be a 'best practice')

My final command looked something like:

`ansible-playbook -i /path/to/my/inventory/file.ini -l server.1.com -l server.2.com my-playbook.yml --check --diff`

Comment: You can also use a single `-l` and [separate the hosts with a `,` or a `:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#common-patterns).